# Calculating Average, A String Tokenization Exercise

Tags: java, string, average, tokenize

I've been trying to get this program working for 3 days now. I've been researching on various websites and stackoverflow as well and I am just not having much success.

The goal is this program is to take in a user input that may be seperated by any amount of white space and also a single semicolon. The integers will then be added and the average will be calculated. The trick is however fractions may also be implemented and can be in the following formats : 12/33 or (12/33).

Fractions are percentage scores out of 100.

I was successfully able to eliminate whitespace and the semicolons I am just unsure how I can do the calculation aspect of this code specially dealing with the fractions.

This is my current code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter a Set of Grades:");
    Scanner messageIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String store = new String();
    store = messageIn.nextLine();
    store = store.trim().replaceAll(" +", "");
    //store = store.trim().replaceAll("(", "");
    //store = store.trim().replaceAll(")", "");
    String[] dataSet = store.split(";");
    //messageIn.close();
    for (int i = 0; i<dataSet.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(dataSet[i]);
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for any help

I haven't gotten this far but for example this code be my input:

98;37; 12/33; (33/90); 88; 120/150;

The output would be:

The Average is: 62.67

Comment: What's your input and what's your desired output?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question with an example. Thank you for your help

Comment: You should be able to just cast the numbers as a double and perform a division.

Comment: How did you get 62.67?

Comment: I see your confusion I think it's the fact that fractional scores are percentage scores out of 100 so they need to be multiplied by 100 after being calculated as a decimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this where you check if the individual grade **[contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-)** a `/` and deal with that case separately:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Initialize scanner object
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Prompt user for input
    System.out.print("Enter a Set of Grades:");
    String store = scanner.nextLine();

    //Remove all white space and round brackets
    store = store.replaceAll("[\\(\\)\\s+]","");

    //Split input into individual grades
    String[] grades = store.split(";");

    double sum = 0;
    //Loop over each entered grade and add to sum variable
    for (String grade : grades) {
      if(grade.contains("/")) {
        double numerator = Double.parseDouble(grade.split("/")[0]);
        double denominator = Double.parseDouble(grade.split("/")[1]);
        sum += numerator/denominator * 100;
      } else {
        sum += Double.parseDouble(grade);
      }
    }

    System.out.printf("The average is: %.2f\n", sum/grades.length);
  }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Enter a Set of Grades: 98;37; 12/33; (33/90); 88; 120/150;
The average is: 62.67
```

Try it out **[here!](https://repl.it/repls/LimegreenGleamingOpensoundsystem)**

Comment: That's a smart idea! Could you explain to me how the .replaceAll method works in: store = store.replaceAll("[\\(\\)\\s+]","");

Comment: Because we want to replace opening and closing round brackets as well all white space we need to use square brackets to say we want to match multiple things. All of the `\\\` are for escaping.

Comment: The `\\s+` specifically matches a sequence of one or more whitespace characters.

Comment: That makes sense thank you so much for the help shash678 this example proved to be really informative and I learned lots about Java from this. Thank You so much for your time in help it is appreciated!